# Not able to push on gitlab

Tags: git

I wrote the commands.

1. `git init`
2. `git add abc.php`
3. `git commit -m "abc"`

But,
I am not able to push my code on gitlab.I am facing error :

```
Couldn't resolve host 'gitlab.com' while accessing
http://<username>:<password>@gitlab.com/<project-folder>/<projectfile>.git
```

fatal: HTTP request failed

Comment: Show the output of `git remote -v`,please

Comment: `Couldn't resolve host 'gitlab.com'` - can you resolve gitlab.com? E.g. does `nslookup gitlab.com` work?

Comment: You need to add the remote to push your changes to. Run `git remote add origin http://path/to-your/repo.git`. This will add remote named `origin`.